# AS2 How to get a movie clip to move forward 20 frames

Tags: actionscript-2, frame, movieclip, forward

I have a movieclip that i want to move forward 20 frames when it touches another movieclip. I dont want it to go to a specific frame number (ex. gotoAndStop(20);)  What ever frame the clip happens to be on, I want it to move forward 20 frames.

Comment: I guess i should add that i have tried, MC.gotoAndPlay(_currentframe+20); but this always moves the mc to frame 20 no matter what the current frame is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 20 frames to `MC`'s `_currentframe` , like this:

```
 MC.gotoAndPlay( MC._currentframe+20 );
```